# How to receive JSON object in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to send a JSON object from an AJAX request to my server.

I'm doing this with JQuery like this:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: settings.ajax.post,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: basket.aggregate(Basket.EXPORT_JSON, qty),
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      if (typeof settings.ajax.success == "function") settings.ajax.success(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, text, e) {
      if (typeof settings.ajax.error == "function") settings.ajax.error(jqXHR, text, e);
    }
  });
```

The url is pointed to this file on the server:

```
<?php

$to = "<my-email-address>";
$subject = "JSON test";
$message = "POST dump:\n\n";

foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
    {
        $message .= $key . ":" . $value;
    }

mail ($to, $subject, $message);

exit;
?>
```

But the POST var seems to be empty, even though in Firebug I can see that the correct data was sent to the server:

[image: Firebug can see the JSON Object]

After each request is sent, the ajax error function is called, with an undefined error (I guess because there was no reply from the server? Or I don't know?)

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST);` output?

Comment: an empty array @ShaquinTrifonoff

Comment: Have a look at this post [link](http://christophercasper.com/2011/10/posting-json-with-jquery-and-php/)

Comment: What about `var_dump($_REQUEST);`? If you still can't get anything, have a look at this: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Huh? Why have you pointed me to load?? @ShaquinTrifonoff

Comment: Thanks @BishnuPaudel for the link, I think that confirms what Sarke just answered

Comment: You can send data using `.load`. I thought that if `ajax` isn't working, then maybe `load` would work ?

Comment: @Ozzy Glad you got the answer.

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff Oh I didn't know that. Well, its sorted now anyway! But thanks. Do you know why I get the error: callback function being called after the request was sent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

POST needs key value pairs, but you're just sending it one value (a JSON string) without a key. It needs to be an array.

Secondly, you need to decode the JSON before you can use it in PHP as an array or object. `json_decode()` is used for that.

Comment: Sure, he forgot parameters. But still, FF sent a string, can't that be accessed in PHP somehow?

Comment: @Bergi well, I don't think its worth answering that, I just changed the `data` param to `data: {json:basket.aggregate(...)}` and I got the JSON string now :)

Comment: @Sarke Thanks, I wonder if you understand the 2nd problem I mentioned - about the callback error function returning an undefined error?

Comment: @Bergi - for the record, as he only submitted a string, it was treated as the key of the key-value pair.  He could have accessed it by examining the array array_keys($_POST), which would have contained the string (in an array with any other POST keys).

Comment: @ernie: Thanks. I was quite sure this was possible, only the OP logged (er, mailed) the keys of the POST array as well but said there would be nothing...

Comment: @Ozzy The error in callback is presumably because the script is not sending any headers, which are evaluated as premature exit for a valid HTTP response.

Comment: Bergi: The message text of the mail was empty until I sent a key:value pair. So @Amit all I have to do is output some HTML?

Comment: or you can simply set the header to 200 ok precisely speaking. `header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK')`

Comment: @bergi - looks like I was mistaken . . . I didn't notice that in the comments he mentioned that var_dump($_POST) returned an empty array.  Sorry for the churn!

Comment: @ernie: Seems like `file_get_contents('php://input');` [[1](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)] is what we needed for that...